# Android - open or restart app after clicking push notification using flag activities

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using push notifications in Android. When I receive a push notification, I want to open the application if it is still running, else it should open a new instance of it.

I am using

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

But when I receive a push notification now and I click on it, nothing happens.

How can I still achieve this by using flagIntents?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the Intent flags on the `Intent`. You were specifying them in the call to get a `PendingIntent`. Try this:

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    notificationIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Ecpet now I have another problem. Is there a way execure te code I have in onCreate(), because it contains the same code the push notification has to do. Now the onCreate isn't called, thus the code is not being executed.

Comment: If you don't set the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, then the current instance of the activity will be destroyed and a new instance will be created (thereby calling `onCreate()`).

Comment: this is not working for me...do you have to set a particular launch mode in the manifest for this activity?

Comment: @Tooroop no you don't. What is not working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I add a flag to the Intent so depending on that flag I open a fragment in my activity. This is OK when I exit my app via back button, but if I exit my app with the home button or when my app is already opened nothing happens.

Comment: Looks like I solved it. My onNewIntent() method wouldn't be called if I set Intent.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or launchMode="singleTop" or even btoh at the same time.
I added :
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
and in the manifest i set launchMode="singleTask". Now it is working as expected

Comment: @Tooroop in general, `singleTask` launch mode is a very bad idea :-( It sounds like you've got something else going on. In general, if you set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVIY_NEW_TASK` and are using your root activity (ie: the starting activity) and your app is already running, Android will just bring your app's task to the front without calling `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as @Tooroop. The target activity of the notification just launches as if no flags were set at all and does not receive a call to onNewIntent. @David Wasser: Why is `singleTask` a bad idea?

Comment: @Moritz perhaps you should post a new question, include your manifest and a description of the problem. It is difficult to diagnose these things in comments to an answer :-( I could write a book about why `singleTask` is a bad idea. Basically you just need to know exactly what you are doing and a lot of developers misuse these launch modes. In general, it creates more problems than it solves: You can end up with multiple tasks which will confuse the user; You need to make sure you have different icons and/or labels for the tasks so as not to confuse the user...

Comment: To solve the mistery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229054/android-pendingintent-from-notification-doesnt-trigger-the-oncreate-if-bring#answer-15230095 @Tooroop

Answer (score 1):

set following things in your Android Mainfest file

```
android:noHistory="true"
 android:launchMode = "singleTop"
```

Comment: Why `android:noHistory="true"` and `android:launchMode = "singleTop"` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case a running application restarted every time I clicked a push notification. But I don't want to restart the application.

In `PendingIntent` I have an intent for needed Activity1 that called Activity2. A bug was in these lines:

```
val intent = Intent(context, Activity2::class.java)
// Remove this line:
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
context.startActivity(intent)
```