# Android: PendingIntent from Notification doesn't trigger the onCreate() if bringing Activity back on Screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

guess I'm having some misunderstandigs with the Intent Flags.. What I'm trying to do is, I'm having a radio streaming applications, which has two Activities (PlayerApplication and SettingsScreen). I have a Service.class for Streaming which runs in the background, which holds a Notification as well (you can stop/start playback in the notification-overlay menu and the PlayerApplication). If the User clicks on the Notification, the PlayerApplicationActivity should be com back to screen.

Everything works fine, expect the case: User opens SettingsScreenActivity -> opens NotificationOverlayMenu -> clicks at Notification -> PendingIntent resumes to PlayerApplicationActivity

Now, PlayerApplicationScreen is there, but I cannot click anything. I see, that the onCreate() of my PlayerApplication isn't triggered, if I resume from Notification. But the layout looks fine (also inflated in the onCreate())

I used following PendingIntent in the Service.class:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
      this.getApplicationContext(), //Service.class
      0, 
      new Intent(this,PlayerApplicationActivity.class)
             .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
      0);
```

So actually the PendingIntent should bring the Activity (if already running) back to the top. Am I using wrong Intents or am I missing a point?

EDIT:
and I declared launchMode in Manifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: Since you have declared `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your `Activity` and it's already running you will receive `onNewIntent` callback instead of `onCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what I was doing wrong:

1. For my purpose I used the wrong launchMode. Right one is `singleTop` not `singleTask`
2. I declared the launchMode in the `<application-node>` instead of the `<activity-node>`

   ```
   //Manifest.xml
   <activity
       android:name="..."
       android:launchMode="singleTop" >
   ```

Answer (score 7):

According to android developer [site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), In `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`,`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and in launch mode : `SingleTask` , If the instance of activity you are calling is already running then instead of creating new instance, it call `onNewIntent()` method. So I think you should check this condition that your activity is running when onCreate() is not calling.

Comment: OMG! All my research finally result in something!!  Thank YOU! Listen to me... just override onNewIntent() and do what you did at onCreate method!!!!!!!

Comment: Long Live Man you saved my day thanks a lot for posting this.